# How to select distinct a substring field or remove duplicate field

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Sample Data:

```
[{url: bing.com},
 {url: bing.com/search?q=test},
 {url: rt.com/test}]
```

Currently what I do is return a filtered url that removed anything after '/'

```
SELECT url,
CASE WHEN LOCATE('/', url) THEN LEFT(url, LOCATE('/', url) - 1)
ELSE url END AS editedUrl
FROM testTable;
```

The output result will now be

```
url[0] = bing.com
url[1] = bing.com
url[2] = rt.com
```

what I want to do is remove duplicate now, which means it will only return `url[0]` and `url[2]`, I tried doing this

```
SELECT DISTINCT url,
CASE WHEN LOCATE('/', url) THEN LEFT(url, LOCATE('/', url) - 1)
ELSE url END AS editedUrl
FROM testTable;
```

However it will compare url base on their actual value rather than after filtered value.

Please assist,
Thanks.

Comment: after getting a result then you can apply `filter` function to get unique value

Comment: If there is duplicated row, which row do you want to reserve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must group by the edited URL:

```
SELECT MIN(url), 
   CASE
      WHEN LOCATE('/', url) THEN LEFT(url, LOCATE('/', url) - 1)
      ELSE url
   END AS editedUrl
FROM testTable
GROUP BY editedUrl
```

If you just want a unique editedUrl:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
   CASE
      WHEN LOCATE('/', url) THEN LEFT(url, LOCATE('/', url) - 1)
      ELSE url
   END AS editedUrl
FROM testTable
```

Comment: The unique editedUrl is what I'm looking for, Thanks A lot.

Answer (score 0):

try to use group by :

```
SELECT url,
CASE WHEN LOCATE('/', url) THEN LEFT(url, LOCATE('/', url) - 1)
ELSE url END AS editedUrl
FROM testTable group by url;
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks. I tried adding `group by LEFT(url, LOCATE('/', url) - 1)` and it works

Comment: yeah.. tag as answered so everyone know this question is already answered

Answer (score 0):

you can automatic remove duplication in one or more COLUMNS if you set a unique key with the option IGNORE on the COLUMN(s) where must be unique like this:

for one COLUMN

```
ALTER IGNORE TABLE yourTable
ADD UNIQUE KEY idx_name (yourField);
```

for two COLUMNs

```
ALTER IGNORE TABLE yourTable
ADD UNIQUE KEY idx_name (yourField,nextField);
```

so you can generate a new COLUM where you store the short URL and after this you can set the key where delete the duplications